# How to split a list in two list

Tags: list, function, ocaml

I have to make a function who splits a number list int two list:

`[Int(17);Float(18.9);Int(777);Float(15.5)]` -> `[Int(17);Int(777)] , [Float(18.9);Float(15.5)]`

```
type number =
  | Int of int
  | Float of float

let rec split_number_list: number list -> number list * number list = function lis ->
  match lis with
  |[] -> li,fi
  |(Int n)::l -> ((Int n)::li,fi)
  |(Float n)::l -> (li,(Float n)::fi)
```

I have two problems. First "Unbound value" appears for `li`, then I tried to create two empty list called `li` and `fi` but that didn't worked. Second I don't know how to call `split_number_list` in the function.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[Int(17);Float(18.9);Int(777);Float(15.5)] -> [17;777] , [18.9;15.5]`, i.e. `number list -> int list * float list`. If you split the numbers by type then it makes little sense to keep the variant type for the result. This will also protect you (at compile time) from e.g. returning `[Int(1);Float(1.0)], [Int(1)]`

Comment: Tip: don't specify the type of functions (unless you have to), the compiler will deduce the type for you. Less to type.

Answer (score 1):

While this looks like homework, and thus it's probably "cheating", the standard library defines [`List.partition`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALpartition), which does exactly this, assuming you can pass it a predicate which determines if a value of type `number` is an integer or not.

```
let is_int n = 
  ...

let split_list lst =
  List.partition is_int lst
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `|[] -> li,fi` or `|(Int n)::l -> ((Int n)::li,fi)`, the compiler is surprised because you're telling it "return li,fi" even though you've never told it what this "li, fi" thing is. There is not variable called "li,fi" at this point so it makes no sense to write that the function should return that.

So you need to define `li,fi` somehow. You can do that using a `let ... in ...` construct:

```ml
type number =
  | Int of int
  | Float of float
;;

let rec split_number_list: number list -> number list * number list =
  function
  |[] -> ...
  |(Int n)::l -> let li,fi = ... in ((Int n)::li, fi)
  |(Float n)::l -> let li,fi = ... in (li, (Float n)::fi)
```

I will let you fill in the blanks.

Hint: Filling the blanks should answer your second question.

An alternative would be to use an auxiliary function with accumulator parameters:

```ml
let split_number_list l =
    let rec helper l il fl =
        match l with
        | [] -> il, fl
        | (Int n)::tl -> helper tl ((Int n)::il) fl
        | (Float x)::tl -> helper tl il ((Float x)::fl)
    in
    let il, fl = helper l [] []
    in
    (List.rev il), (List.rev fl)
```

Comment: I would suggest this is a good place to use `as`.  E.g. `(Int _ as n)::tl -> helper tl (n :: il) fl`